# Inherited class doesn't have attributes?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, polymorphism, jira

I'm using the [jira-ruby](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby%20%22jira-ruby') library, and have extended the `JIRA::Resource::Issue` class as defined below.

```
class ServerRequest < JIRA::Resource::Issue
  def requested_os
    customfield_11169
  end
end
```

When I create a new `ServerRequest` object, I am unable to access attributes like I can when the object is of type `JIRA::Resource::Issue`

Ex.

```
[81] pry(main)> ticket.class
=> JIRA::Resource::Issue
[80] pry(main)> ticket.customfield_11169
=>{"self"=>"http://REDACTED:8080/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14451",
"value"=>"Linux - CentOS","id"=>"14451"}
[81] pry(main)> request = ServerRequest.new(ticket)
[82] pry(main)> request.class
=> ServerRequest
[83] pry(main)> request.customfield_11169
NoMethodError: undefined method `customfield_11169' for #<ServerRequest:0x005634b57431b0>
from /home/user/.gem/ruby/gems/jira-ruby-1.1.0/lib/jira/base.rb:308:in `method_missing'
```

I've tried to read through the [`JIRA::Resource::Base`](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/blob/master/lib/jira/base.rb) class, but I'm not sure I have a clear understanding of how it's mapping my method calls on the class to the attribute hash, or why my extended class does not do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, when a method called is not found, the method `method_missing` is called, passing the method name, the arguments, and the block used in the call. `JIRA::Resource::Issue`, has a definition for `method_missing`:

https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby/blob/master/lib/jira/resource/issue.rb#L89

In the definition is possible verify that it's searching first the `attrs['fields']` hash for the value, and if not found it calls `method_missing` from the parent class, that search in `attrs`.

`attrs` apparently is setted when the object is initialized. How do you initialize the objects in your example?

Comment: Perfect answer. I read into the `method_missing` method and was able to determine that I hadn't instantiated the `@attrs` variable properly. Adding a call to `super` in the `initialize` method resolved the issue.